# Перестала работать архивация по rsync

Tags: linux, администрирование

Несколько лет у меня по *cron*-у ежедневно выполнялась архивация таким скриптом:

```
#! /bin/bash
# Сохранение папки "Документы" на сервере

LOG_FILE=/home/lary/.rsync.log
DDD=`date`

echo "=== Начало архивирования: $DDD ===" >> $LOG_FILE
rsync   -e 'ssh -i /home/lary/.ssh/rsync' \
    --log-file=$LOG_FILE \
    --stats \
    --archive \
    --delete \
    /home/lary/Документы  \
    larionov@172.17.132.145:/home/larionov/Archive/ >> $LOG_FILE  2>&1
echo "=== Архивирование завершено ==="  >> $LOG_FILE
```

Я даже забыл про него. Но, недавно, обнаружил, что архивация перестала выполняться. Когда начал с этим делом разбираться, то выяснилось, что:

1. Если запустить скрипт вручную, то система запрашивает(!!!) ввод пароля.
2. Если пароль ввести - всё отрабатывает нормально
3. При запуске из под крона пароль вводить некому - скрипт снимается.
4. Вспомнил, что недавно наш сервер "переехал" на другой IP. В скрипте я тогда адрес исправил, но работоспособность не проверял.
5. Подозреваю, что аутентификация по ключу из файла *~/.ssh/rsync* перестала работать из-за того, что что-то надо изменить  в файле известных *ssh* ключей: *~/.ssh/known_hosts* так как изменился IP сервера.

Но вот что там надо сделать ?

Comment: звучит так будто при переезде потерялся публичный ключ на **сервере**.... просто скопировать его заново не помогает? если при ручном запуске на хост жалоб нет, то с `known_hosts` должно быть всё в пордке...

Comment: *ssh-copy-id* вам в помощь, и да, нужно будет удалить старый fingerprint сервера из *known_hosts*.

Comment: **потерялся публичный ключ на сервере** - А как его туда положить? В моём домашнем (на сервере)  каталоге есть папка *.ssh*, но там лежит что-то не очень понятное...

Comment: 1) **ssh-copy-id вам в помощь** - спасибо, читаю. **нужно будет удалить старый** - проблема в том, что там не понятно, какой ключ куда относится... Во всяком случае, навскидку я не увидел.

Comment: Ничего не понимаю :-( Делаю всё по инструкции, никаких сообщений об ошибках не выдаётся, но никакого эффекта нет!  Мой rsa ключ для бэкапа на сервер называется rsync.pub. Делаю так:

Comment: ssh-copy-id -i rsync.pub larionov@192.168.1.1

Comment: Утилита спрашивает мой пароль на сервере и выполняет некоторые действия, в конце концов выдавая сообщение: *Number of key(s) added: 1*

Comment: И рекомендует проверить, что вход теперь будет только по ключу: *Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'larionov@192.168.1.1'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.*

Comment: Пытаюсь войти: *$ ssh larionov@192.168.1.1*

Comment: И нарываюсь на запрос: *larionov@192.168.1.1's password:*   Да какого хрена ?!!!!

Comment: Да, забыл упомянуть, что на сервере файл *rsync.pub* действительно лежит в папке *.ssh* и дата у него - свежая.